# 2010 Hyundia i30 - Should I keep the batter lead removed in order to prevent the battery from flattening out?

Tags: battery, battery-drain

I drive 2010 Hyundia i30. I recently had my battery flat out after I did not use it for 3 months. The mechanic who helped with the battery situation suggested that I can keep one of the battery leads disconnected if I am not planning to drive the vehicle for more than a week. There is generally nothing unsafe in this IMO but last time my batter was disconnected, the dashboard started showing "ESP OFF" (Electronic Stability Programme) sign. I am not sure what harm that does but car drove ok with that sign on.

Is there any harm in keeping one lead of batter disconnected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably better off starting and driving the car everyday or leaving a battery tender on the car. Some cars learn and store values like idle, etc... When the battery is disconnected it loses these values. There's no real harm in disconnecting the battery, just some inconveniences that may or may not require scantools to resolve.